# How to use relative path with CorrectFilePaths when the software doesn't?

Tags: windows

I would like to use relative path with a compatibility shim using CorrectFilePaths because i'm unable to know in advance where the software will be installed, the source directory will always be to a relative location to where the executable runs but the destination is not relative and should be inside user's profile.

My tries were unsuccessful, with a basic rule of `"\Config\";"%appdata%\MySoftware\Config"` giving as result `"X:\Programs\MySoftwareX:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\MySoftware\Config"` while it should have been `"X:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\MySoftware\Config"`

Comment: I see `%USERAPPDATA%`  and `%ALLAPPDATA%` but not `%appdata%` in the reference for [Using the CorrectFilePaths Fix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766201(v=ws.10).aspx).